# Puppet Server/Client Connection Failed

Tags: puppet

I have a couple of parallel Vms on my Mac and i am trying to set up a simple connection between those as a puppet master and puppet client.

1. Puppet Master (on CentOs 6.2)
2. Puppet Client (on Ubuntu 12.1 Server)

when trying to connect the client using the following command.

```
puppet agent --server 192.168.1.103 --waitforcert 60 --test --verbose
```

It tries to connect with the following output

```
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
info: Caching certificate for ca
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for puppet1.localdomain
info: Certificate Request fingerprint (md5) : 2E:C6:D2:C2:........
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
notice: Did not receive certificate
```

On the server side i have the debugging puppet master listening with the following output:

```
notice: Starting Puppet master version 2.7.14
err: Could not resolve 192.168.1.101: no name for 192.168.1.101
info: access[^/catalog/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[^/catalog/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
info: access[^/node/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[^/node/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
info: access[/certificate_revocation_list/ca]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[/certificate_revocation_list/ca]: allowing * access
info: access[/report]: allowing 'method' save
info: access[/report]: allowing * access
info: access[/file]: allowing * access
info: access[/certificate/ca]: adding authentication any
info: access[/certificate/ca]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[/certificate/ca]: allowing * access
info: access[/certificate/]: adding authentication any
info: access[/certificate/]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[/certificate/]: allowing * access
info: access[/certificate_request]: adding authentication any
info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing 'method' save
info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing * access
info: access[/]: adding authentication any
info: Inserting default '/status' (auth true) ACL because none were found in '/etc/puppet/auth.conf'
err: Could not resolve 192.168.1.101: no name for 192.168.1.101
info: Could not find certificate for 'puppet1.localdomain'
err: Could not resolve 192.168.1.101: no name for 192.168.1.101
info: Could not find certificate_request for 'puppet1.localdomain'
err: Could not resolve 192.168.1.101: no name for 192.168.1.101
notice: puppet1.localdomain has a waiting certificate request
err: Could not resolve 192.168.1.101: no name for 192.168.1.101
info: Could not find certificate for 'puppet1.localdomain'
err: Could not resolve 192.168.1.101: no name for 192.168.1.101
info: Could not find certificate for 'puppet1.localdomain'
err: Could not resolve 192.168.1.101: no name for 192.168.1.101
info: Could not find certificate for 'puppet1.localdomain'
err: Could not resolve 192.168.1.101: no name for 192.168.1.101
info: Could not find certificate for 'puppet1.localdomain'
```

Is it possible to set a simple puppet configuration without using host resolution and just simple ip address?

Any help?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but may solve your problem. You can use avahi/mdns to provide local dns resolution. Just install it on centos and Ubuntu and you should be able to ping hostname.local

Comment: I don't mind setting another vm as a domain controller but just would like to know if somebody set this up using only ip address

Comment: Have you tried running this using sudo?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue just adding both VM's ip's on the /etc/hosts file. Then puppet is working for me fine.